# Which sanctions can be applied by airline to me if I use round trip ticket as a one way

Tags: air-travel, fares

I want to travel from city A to city B. Round trip ticket costs much less than one-way. So I want to buy a round trip ticket and travel only in one direction. What airline can do to me to punish such a life hack? Will I have any problems with this?

Comment: Not a duplicate, in my opinion. The other question asks why pricing is done this way, this question asks what the penalties would be if the airline catches you.